# Google Cloud SQL: Acess Denied from App Engine only

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I'm accessing Cloud SQL from App Engine in the same project. I have set the password to the root user. I'm able to connect from mysql command line remotely thusly:

```
C:>mysql -u root -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p <- IP address of my Cloud SQL  
Enter password: <--- I supply passw0rd
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.  
Your MySQL connection id is 20913  
Server version: 5.7.14-google-log (Google)
```

However, when I try from App Engine:

Code snippet:

```
url = "jdbc:google:mysql://myproject:us-central1:myinst/mydb?user=root;password=passw0rd";
conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

The error I get is:

```
com.google.gae.server.Connect getConnection: ERROR. Could not get connection. Access denied for user  'root;password=passw0rd'@'cloudsqlproxy~xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (using password: NO)
```

I have tried the url with just the user only, but no luck.
Appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Found my error. The Java URL should have been:

```
url = "jdbc:google:mysql://myproject:us-central1:myinst/mydb?user=root&password=passw0rd";
```

I replaced the **;** with **&**.
Works now.

Comment: ya, GET request query params should be combined with `&` not `;`